# Button click event is not working in netbeans java

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in java programming. I need if I click jButton1 relevant message should display "HI" if I click jButton2 relevant message should display "bye" but it is not working. I am written the code on NetBeans.

```
  private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
     private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;

 public main() {
        initComponents();

 jButton1.addActionListener(this);

    }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                if(evt.getSource() == jButton1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hi");
                }
                else if(evt.getSource() == jButton2)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "bye");
                }    
            }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Use one button, not two, for the MRE / SSCCE..

Comment: You need to use the `addActionListener(...)` method to add the ActionListener to each button. Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There is a section on `How to Use Buttons` or `How to Write an ActionListener` to get you started.

Comment: jButton1.addActionListener(this); i add this inside the public main() but wont work sir.

Comment: Tips: 1) Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) The latest edit is also not an MRE / SSCCE. Minus one for not reading the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow this example :-

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

```
JButton button1, button2;

public JButtonDemo() {
    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setText("Click Me 1");
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    add(button1);

    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setText("Click Me 2");
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    add(button2);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == button1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hi");
    } else if (ae.getSource() == button2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "bye");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JButon Demo Example ");
    f.setContentPane(new JButtonDemo());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: jButton1.addActionListener(this); 
    jButton2.addActionListener(this); main cannot be convert to actionlistener

Comment: jButton1.addActionListener(this); jButton2.addActionListener(this); main cannot be convert to actionlistener error displayed

Comment: sir netbeans button look like this private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
     private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;

Comment: I had used this to import buttons :-

import javax.swing.*;